# visual studio 2008 macro: write to output pane

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, macros

In a Visual Studio macro, how do you write execution information on the output pane (i.e. the window that usually contains build output)?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, if that is relevant.

**Solution**: I added the following subs to my macro project, I'm posting them here in case they could be useful.

```
Private Sub Write(ByVal name As String, ByVal message As String)
    Dim output As Window = DTE.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindOutput)
    Dim window As OutputWindow = output.Object
    Dim pane As OutputWindowPane = window.OutputWindowPanes.Item(name)
    pane.Activate()
    pane.OutputString(message)
    pane.OutputString(Environment.NewLine)
End Sub

Private Sub Log(ByVal message As String, ByVal ParamArray args() As Object)
    Write("Debug", String.Format(message, args))
End Sub

Private Sub Log(ByVal message As String)
    Write("Debug", message)
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably better to post your solution as an answer and then accept it.